# Rancher - cluster node has disk pressure

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, proxmox

I am new to Rancher and Kubernetes so I'll appreciate it if you can help me on this one.

I have a Proxmox VM (Ubuntu server 20.04.2) on which I have installed Docker and Kubernetes and containerized Rancher. I have only this one node.
Currently I have dedicated 60GB to the Ubuntu server (which can expand up to 465GB).

My cluster is displayed as Unavailable. The error message is "Node has disk pressure".

I read that this may be caused by a large amount of log files and tried increasing the disk size of the Ubuntu server (it was previously 20GB), but this didn't solve the issue.

I had a similar issue with a pod previously and restarting the Ubuntu server fixed it.
I tried restarting Ubuntu, and the whole Proxmox server as well, but nothing solved it this time.

df -i says only 20% of inodes used

I am completely lost as to how to fix this issue and what is causing it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO @LubomirKrustev :) Could you please run `kubectl describe node` and edit your question with the output?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @WytrzymałyWiktor, 
I seemed to have an issue with the whole VM. This is my homelab setup, so I just re-installed the whole thing. I am currently setting Kubernetes anew. 
I'll let you know if I run into the same issue again.